# Print easy_breadcrumb block to template

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

I'm trying to print out a block to my template, it's a custom block which comes with the 'easy_breadcrumb' module.

Normally I would print out a block using the following:

```
<?php
    $block = module_invoke('block', 'block_view', 'ID');
    print render($block['content']); 
?>
```

I've tried:

```
<?php
    $block = module_invoke('block', 'block_view', 'easy_breadcrumb');
    print render($block['content']); 
?>
```

It doesn't specify an ID in the admin and that is where i'm getting stuck.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the block delts was 'easy_breadcrumb' was able to locate this inside the modules config files e.g. `module_name/module_name.module`

```
$block = module_invoke('easy_breadcrumb', 'block_view', 'easy_breadcrumb');
print render($block['content']);
```

Answer (score 0):

If the module only creates one block then its id will be 0 so this should work

```
$block = module_invoke('easy_breadcrumb', 'block_view', '0');
print render($block['content']);
```

Answer (score 0):

to get correct information on delta and module name, you can check "block" table in drupal database, there are columns "module", "delta"